# Get Data from SensorSimulator

Tags: java, android, acceleration

i tried to build a litte app to readout the data from SensorSimulator

http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

I installed the SensorSimulatorSettings-App and followed the instructions on the Website.
When i start my AVD and then the App i can connect to the stand-alone programm and see the values.

Then i started my own program which source code you can lookup here:
http://nopaste.info/093cfd38af.html

I thought i followed the instructions given on SensorSimulator, but when I start my app on the emulator i just see a white sheet without any values and my catlog says:

"launch timeout has expired giving up wake lock!"
And when I restart the AVD I cannot run the SensorSimulatorSettings-App anymore, it crashes now too.

I really cannot see what I have done wrong and really need your help, even if it's a dumb question.

I really Thank you in advice.

Regards

Comment: Can you add some more info like what version of SDK, what Android emulator you are running on (2.3, 3.0, 4.0?)